# Reputation Tracker now covers SOFU, Meta SO and Programmers SE

Tags: discussion, reputation

I don't know if anyone's actually using my [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) tool, but it now lets you select which sites you want to see reputation for.

For example, the URL for me to find out how I've done today on Stack Overflow and Meta is: [http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?user=22656&mode=today&sites=so,meta](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?user=22656&mode=day&sites=so,meta)

Adjust for your own user ID.

I know the UI is somewhat crude — I wasn't sure whether to try to put the tables side-by-side or not.

Comment: Who's Ann? Or is that short for something ("announcement", perhaps)?

Comment: Yes, announcement. I figured it wouldn't take up as much space this way :)

Comment: Btw - are you allowing for the different ids? For example, I'm 1202 on SF, but 23354 on both SO and meta

Comment: Ah. No, I'm not at the moment. Rats... I thought all the user IDs were harmonised. (Mine are.) Hmm. I might introduce a comma-separated user ID format for that case. Ick.

Comment: No, you're user #173 on SF (http://serverfault.com/users/173/jon-skeet). It's just SO and meta that share IDs.

Comment: Oops - serves me right for not checking. Okay, I'll look into that tomorrow.

Comment: btw, the "yesterday" etc boxes don't carry this over either; not exactly critical (it already does everything I'd want in regular use)

Comment: Could you make it retain the sites= parameter? It's a bit of a pain clicking one of the options and have to re-add it. Aside from that, seems quite useful!

Comment: @dbr: Yes, I'll give it a go - although the expected use is to have a bookmark :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: The app link is broken. Is the tracker still available somewhere or it is removed?

Comment: @HimanshuJansari: I'm afraid it suffered from bit-rot and I removed it a few years ago.

Comment: @JonSkeet: So you have stopped tracking your reputation :)